# How to make sure that children live after an exec-call?

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

Is there a safe way or common practice of how I can make sure, that my with `execvp` executed children lives in a good state?

For example: I let the user of my program pick a custom processor for some of the data in the program (lets say he wants to process them with `bzip2 -zc -`). I create this process with the usual `fork()`, `execvp()` and for each stdin, stdout and stderr a `pipe(), dup2()`. But I can't influence whether the user gave me a correct command-call or something that will die because some argument is wrong (for example, he might give me `cat foo` but the file foo does not exist and thus cat will exit immediately).

Can I somehow make sure that at least after I executed this user-command and before I start feeding it with input it is in a good state - waiting for my input - and not already dead or dying?

Comment: Check if your write succeeds.  If the child on the other end of the pipe dies without reading any data, the write will fail and you will (usually) get a SIGPIPE and a SIGCHLD.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
waitpid(ChildPID, &status, WNOHANG);
```

if it returns `0` means child is alive.

Answer (score 0):

The father will receive a SIGPIPE if a pipe connecting him to the child is closed.  If the child dies, all those pipes are closed, hence a SIGPIPE is sent.

Comment: I believe the parent process would get a `SIGPIPE` only when it tries to `write` on the closed pipe.

Comment: Or when it tries to read from such a pipe.  If the parent does neither, then it does not need to care whether the child is running.  At least in this scenario (user-defined converter).

Comment: sry for the late replay. That is what I'm currently doing to prevent crashes and misbehaviour. But that makes error-handling guess-work at best - you never know why the child died (like with my example of the wrong command-string).

Comment: For finding out more you have to look at the exit code and capture the stdout and stderr of the child.  Anything else (like using `strace` or similar) would be overkill, I assume.